# Write numpy array to binary file efficiently

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, binary, dask

I need an efficient solution for writing a large amount of data to a binary file. Currently I use the numpy method `.tofile`, which consumes most of the runtime. My MWE:

```
import numpy as np

def writeCFloat(f, ndarray):
    np.asarray(ndarray, dtype=np.float32).tofile(f)
def writeCInt(f, ndarray):
    np.asarray(ndarray, dtype=np.int32).tofile(f)
def writeC80(f, string):
    np.asarray(string, dtype='a80').tofile(f)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    f = open('test.out', mode='wb')
    ndarray = np.zeros((10000,10000))

    writeCInt(f, ndarray)
    writeCFloat(f, ndarray)
    writeC80(f, 'coordinates')
```

So is there a more efficient way than the current solution? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Considering that you have no explicit loops in your code and that the documentation for `asarray` says *No copy is performed if the input
        is already an ndarray.*, I would think there is no faster way.

Comment: Why is this current solution too slow?  Do you have benchmarks showing that python can achieve a higher IO rate, or is this a script that needs to write lots of data in realtime?

Comment: Thanks for your replies. What I'm currently doing is reading a large binary file (~40 Gb) and afterwards writing the data back to another binary file. I've profiled the python script and found that most of the time is spent by `.tofile`. So I was wondering if there is space for improvement by an alternative way to write arrays, strings etc. to a binary file?

Comment: Maybe [`dask`](https://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/use-cases.html) is an option for you? In general parallelism can give you a speed-up, the question then is how you would implement it, but that depends on the details of your use case.

Comment: Looks fine to me also.  You might also consider various options offered by pandas (like HDF, feather, or parquet) and dask.

Comment: Considering parallelism another option would be to use the [File IO of MPI](https://mpi4py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html#mpi-io).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dask` to run this operation in parallel. This also allows you to scale beyond the memory limits of a single thread.

Depending on your use case and the filetype you want the data to end up in, you could do the following:

**MCVE**

```py
import numpy as np
import dask.array as da

def writeCFloat_dask(ndarray):
    da.from_array(ndarray).astype('float32').to_zarr('float32.zarr')
def writeCInt_dask(ndarray):
    da.from_array(ndarray).astype('int32').to_zarr('int32.zarr')
def writeC80_dask(string):
    da.from_array(string).astype('a80').to_zarr('a80.zarr')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    ndarray = np.zeros((100000,10000))

    writeCInt_dask(ndarray)
    writeCFloat_dask(ndarray)
    writeC80_dask('coordinates')
```

Alternatively, if you want to write all arrays to a single file you could write to HDF5 instead using the following:

```py
def returnCFloat_dask(ndarray):
    return da.from_array(ndarray).astype('float32')
def returnCInt_dask(ndarray):
    return da.from_array(ndarray).astype('int32')
def returnC80_dask(string):
    return da.from_array(string).astype('a80')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ndarray = np.zeros((100000,10000))

    da_float = returnCFloat_dask(ndarray)
    da_int = returnCInt_dask(ndarray)
    da_string = returnC80_dask('coordinates')

    da.to_hdf5('test-out.hdf5', {'/float': da_float, '/int': da_int, '/string': da_string})
```

See the [documentation on writing arrays to binary file types with Dask](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/array-creation.html#hdf5) for more information.